# How to read from a string as if reading from a file in fortran?

Tags: string, io, stream, fortran, eol

The following code is attempting to read a file into a memory block storing characters and read data from that block instead of the original file. ( The code is modified based on [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#Fortran) )

```
      program read_file
      implicit none
      integer :: n
      character(len=:), allocatable :: s
      character(len=5) :: a, b

      open(unit=10, file="read_file.f", action="read",
 1     form="unformatted", access="stream")
      inquire(unit=10, size=n)
      allocate(character(n) :: s)

      read(10) s
      close(10)

      print "(A)", s

      read ( s, * ) a

      read ( s, * ) b

      print *, a

      print * , b ! meant to read from the previously visited place

      end program read_file
```

When trying to read from the character block 's', the program always reads from the beginning of it rather than reads continuously as reading a text file. So 'a' and 'b' are exactly the same. Is there a way to read 's' as if it read from a file ? Thanks!

Comment: it shows 'end-of-file during read' error out of this modification.

Comment: There is no "current location" in the string `s`. In files, you read record by record and each `read` goes to the next record. Add `print *, 'n is', n` before the error. Also, please provide a test file :-)

Comment: So it seems impossible to parse a string in the way that it reads from a real file. Still is there any chance to circumvent this by a statement to read until EOL ?  And the code provided is self-contained, i.e., the executable file reads its source code.

Comment: You are right and the purpose I am using internal read is to 'parse' a strings which is the text in a file to other types ( maybe characters or integers, etc. ). Extracting substrings is not the motive anyway. The difficulty I have is that the 'read' statement cannot walk through the string line by line. You were asking about the length of 's' which I think in this case is 519, total number of characters within the source code I posted.

Comment: Looks to me like you might want `s(1:index(s,line_end))` to get the first line of `s` (ion course, you have to set `line_end` to the character that represents a line end). But the reason I asked how long `s` is was to be sure that reading `s` had worked in the first place.  At this point, I'm quite sure you are using the wrong approach to splitting `s`, figure out where the line-ends are, use them in string index expressions.  Internal reads are not the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks and now I am reading line by line to an array of strings